# Временные пояса и отображение правильного времени

Tags: php

На сервере стоит дефолтный временной часовой пояс.
Когда пользователь регистрируется - определяется его часовое смещение.
При публикации пользователем информации высчитывается его настоящее время с учетом его зафиксированного смещения:

**Например:**

```
-120 - 2 часа разница
+120 - на 2 часа больше
```

**Сложность:**
При публикации пользователем для контента фиксируется время, определенное заданным смещением часового пояса пользователя. Например:

```
Киев - 19:00,  Москва - 20:00
```

Человек из Киева публикует новость в 19:00, после чего человек из Москвы видит, что новость опубликована не в 20:00, а в 19:00 по киевскому. А должно отобразиться 20:00 с учетом часового пояса текущего пользователя.

Какие есть идеи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не используйте "смещения". Вам мало того, что в данный момент твориться с часовыми поясами в России? Плюс, в некоторых странах смещение не является целым числом часов (например, для Индии смещение будет кратное половине часа, а для некоторых стран даже кратным 15 минутам).

Поэтому правильно делать так. В базе хранить время в utc. А вот для каждого пользователя выводить, учитывая его часовой пояс.

Правда, в случае php этот вариант имеет один нюанс. Многие провайдеры не до конца обновляют файл tzdata (с данными о часовых поясах) и в результате php живет [своей жизнью](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/37473/). Но рецепт от этого есть, и, к счастью, эта проблема касается только тех стран, которые активно меняют свой часовой пояс. Но как только выкатите нормальный файл, большинство дат нормализируется.

Comment: Время в UTC - что за формат? Как проверить, где он выставлен?

Comment: Раскройте подробнее, пожалуйста, Ваш ответ. Не ясно, где определять UTC, хранить или это время на сервере?

Comment: Срочно изучите, что такое [UTC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)!